# Error on entering data in a form in VBA access

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hello i am using a form in ACCESS to enter new data for a company. First of all the form shows me the current data with a query , and when i want to introduce a new data in the fiels in a line i press Tab many times and when ends it gave   me an Error:

```
the data was added to the database but the data won't be displayed in the form because it 
doesn't satisfy
```

and i close the form and when i open again the form for that company the values that i entered are there...
how can i solve this error , any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some rudimentary error trapping.  If your code doesn't already contain it, you really need to read up on it.  Any code **without** some error trapping is just flat out poorly written code.

To start, use a shell like this and modify it appropriately:

```
Sub|Function SomeName()
    On Error GoTo Err_SomeName          ' Initialize error handling.
    ' Code to do something here.

Exit_SomeName:                          ' Label to resume after error.
    Exit Sub|Function                   ' Exit before error handler.

Err_SomeName:                           ' Label to jump to on error.
    MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description ' Place error handling here.
    Resume Exit_SomeName                ' Pick up again and quit.
End Sub|Function
```

If it hits an error, it will jump to the Err_SomeName: line and then display a messagebox with the error number and description.  It will then exit the Sub/Function.  What you really want to do is instead of just popping up a messagebox, do something that actually **solves** the problem.  This is what error handling is all about, and it's critical to ensure your program functions exactly the way it's supposed to.